# WordPress WooCommerce Variation Dropdown Html Override

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

Basically, I want to convert my variation dropdown into something fancy, like for example, make it a radio button.

But this filter is not working. As a sample, I'm using it like this.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'override_color_variation_display', 10, 2 );

public function override_color_variation_display( $html, $args ) {
    $html = 'Some override';

    return $html;
}
```

Is this the correct way to get this working? Because it's not showing the "Some override" text anywhere on the product display.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which WooCommerce version are you using but in 2.5.1 this filter accepts only one variable. Try this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'override_color_variation_display');

function override_color_variation_display( $html ) {
    $html = 'Some override';

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: according here:
https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/tag/woocommerce-2-5/
it could accept two parameters now for 2.5.1.

I've attempted doing that as well, actually I've tried it initially like that but it's not working.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. Then it should work. Are you sure that the filter is firing and that the method "wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options" is being called?

Comment: Yes Im very sure, and there's nothing popping out on debug. I gave up on this one and overridden "wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options" from my themes function.php