# Eliminate Hide or Remove "Services" and "Clear" from the Variation Drop Down in WooCommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

[image]

W/o altering the **template** can we eliminate **"services"** and **"clear"** from the variation dropdown system.

I have copy-pasted a template in a theme, and its modification was successful, but I am looking for ways to get rid of this through some hook/function without altering any template whatsoever.

Comment: Why don't you want to modify the theme template? That sounds exactly like what a child theme is for.

Comment: Sir, I have put a folder in theme by the name of woocommerce. Looking to minimize as little I should customize templates that might create a future hassle when woo-commerce goes through severe changes.

Comment: I think there is a way. My agenda is to touch templates as minimum as we can.

Comment: If you're only worried about altering the template, would CSS changes work for you?

Comment: Yes thats an option that I tried successfully, but also trying to achieve through some hooks/functions, if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove variation reset "clear" button using below hook

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_reset_variations_link', '__return_false' );
```

Remove attribute label using the hook below

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label', '__return_false' );
```