# Woocommerce variation dropdown option tag add some dataset

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

```
<select class="license_type" name="license_type" id="license_type">
    <option value="license" data-set="500">Single Site License</option>
    <option value="license" data-set="700">5 Site License</option>
    <option value="license" data-set="1400">Developers License</option>
</select>
```

In the woocommerce variation product - I want to add some data-set tags in option tag.

```
data-set="<? php  some code here to pull the price of the variation ?>"
```

Is that possible through hook/filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_price_of_current_variant($product, $name, $term_slug) {

    $price = 0;
    foreach ($product->get_available_variations() as $variation) {
        if ($variation['attributes'][$name] == $term_slug)
        $price = $variation['display_price'];
    }

    return $price;
}


add_filter('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'wt_modifiy_variation_options', 10, 2);

function wt_modifiy_variation_options($html, $args) {


    $options = $args['options'];
    $product = $args['product'];
    $attribute = $args['attribute']; // The product attribute taxonomy
    $name = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_' . sanitize_title($attribute);
    $id = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title($attribute);
    $class = $args['class'];
    $show_option_none = $args['show_option_none'] ? true : false;
    $show_option_none_text = __('Add your custom text in here', 'woocommerce');

    if (empty($options) && !empty($product) && !empty($attribute)) {
        $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
        $options = $attributes[$attribute];
    }

    $html = '<select id="' . esc_attr($id) . '" class="' . esc_attr($class) . 'customdropdown" name="' . esc_attr($name) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr(sanitize_title($attribute)) . '" data-show_option_none="' . ( $show_option_none ? 'yes' : 'no' ) . '">';
    $html .= '<option value="">' . esc_html($show_option_none_text) . '</option>';



    if (!empty($options)) {
        if ($product && taxonomy_exists($attribute)) {
            $terms = wc_get_product_terms($product->get_id(), $attribute, array('fields' => 'all'));


            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                if (in_array($term->slug, $options)) {

                    $variat_price = get_price_of_current_variant($product, $name, $term->slug);


                    $data_attr = "data-custom=$variat_price";
                    $html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr($term->slug) . '" ' . selected(sanitize_title($args['selected']), $term->slug, false) . $data_attr . '>' . esc_html(apply_filters('woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name)) . '</option>';
                }
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($options as $option) {

                $selected = sanitize_title($args['selected']) === $args['selected'] ? selected($args['selected'], sanitize_title($option), false) : selected($args['selected'], $option, false);

                $variat_price = get_price_of_current_variant($product, $name, $option);

                $data_attr = "data-custom=$variat_price";
                $html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr($option) . '" ' . $selected . $data_attr . '>' .
                        esc_html(apply_filters('woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option)) . '</option>';
            }
        }
    }
    $html .= '</select>';


    return $html;
}
```

This is the code for what you are looking..

Comment: I have also executed this (solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58292681/custom-html-for-woocommerce-product-variation-dropdown) wont they conflict together?

Comment: Not working → `<option value="5-site-license" data-custom="0" class="attached enabled">5 Site License</option>`

Comment: Custom class/id/name code causing issue?https://www.screencast.com/t/LPhgHHQ0ZSTa

Comment: Yes, that is causing an issue. How can we implement both with conflict or contradiction?

Comment: Please reply sir.

Comment: @wocommerce115 You don't need both codes at a time. Add the class through the above snippet.

Comment: Sir, Would it be possible for you to club both the codes together?

Comment: @wocommerce115 - Updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201242/discussion-between-wocommerce115-and-mujuonly).

Comment: No other way to introduce data-custom in the options tags?

Comment: After implementing your solution some features of my custom.js stops working. sorry for so inquisitive.

Comment: Can u also solve this → https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58495243/generate-js-variable-array-through-data-set-from-woocommerce-html-variation

Comment: Hey there, Can you also help me with this piece → https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58556085/add-meta-information-when-product-custom-checkbox-option-that-changes-woocommerc

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. You can use this

`apply_filters( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', $html, $args )`

filter to achieve your above tasks.

Comment: One [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053053/wordpress-woocommerce-variation-dropdown-html-override) also, but the proper solution is not given.