# Generate JS variable array through data-set from woocommerce HTML variation

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce, dataset, hook-woocommerce

This is the part of a vanilla JS code =

```
var prices = [100, 536, 2368];
```

But the above is hardcoded. I want them through an HTML select drop down:

```
<select class="license_type" name="license_type" id="license_type">
    <option value="license" data-price="500">Single Site License</option>
    <option value="license" data-price="700">5 Site License</option>
    <option value="license" data-price="1400">Developers License</option>
</select>
```

Here values in the dataset are generated dynamically in woocommerce:

[image]

Data sets values will be dynamically generated based on the woocommerce product.

How can we make sure that the array `var prices` is up to date always dynamically on each product page based on the variable prices?

**Update →**

There is a connection to this question answered here→
[Woocommerce variation dropdown option tag add some dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58468876/woocommerce-variation-dropdown-option-tag-add-some-dataset)

(This is how we are introducing data-set in HTML of options tag)

Finally in browser it will be rendered like this:

[image]

Comment: On a select field, each option value should be different normally… Now with the provided code and details, how people can guess your question?

Comment: Sir, Updated the question let me know if it improves the question?

Comment: Currently, there is hardcoded vanilla JS →`var prices = [100, 536, 2368]; but I want that this array should generate from data-price in options HTML.
`

Comment: I am eager to improve this question if even now I am unable to convey the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'webtoffee_product_attr_filter' );

    function webtoffee_product_attr_filter() {
       if ( !is_product() ) {
          return;
       }
       ?>
          add_action('wp_footer', 'webtoffee_checkout_shipping_filter_it_states');

    function webtoffee_checkout_shipping_filter_it_states() {
        if (!is_product()) {
            return;
        }
        ?>

       <script>

        var x = document.getElementById("color");
        var prices = new Array();;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if(x.options[i].getAttribute('data-custom')){
            prices.push(x.options[i].getAttribute('data-custom'));
        }else{
            prices.push("0");
        }
        };
        console.log(prices);
        </script>

    <?php
}
```

Try this

Comment: what is color here?

Comment: Is there a way around so that the final array will be like [0, 69, 79]. First should be 0 to take care of select an option part.

Comment: You are very knowledgeable sir. How many months/years does one needs to reach at this stage?

Comment: Could you also fix this → https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58514945/using-map-method-generate-js-variable-array-through-data-set-from-woocommerce-ht

Comment: Sir, Would you be able to help me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58607266/failing-to-add-meta-information-on-the-woocommerce-cart-page)